Program source code gets truncated while copying. Width is less by 20 characters
I copied a RPGLE source from Production Library to my programmer's library so that I could modify the code but the characters at the end got truncated. Please help.
I can see that the length is 100 in Prod library but in my library its 80.
I copied the RPGLE source to my own library and i can see that the right side of the program is missing

When you create the source file in your own library, specify RCDLEN(112). The default for CRTSRCPF is 92, so it only supports a line-length of 80.
CRTSRCPF FILE(MYLIB/QRPGLESRC) RCDLEN(112) 

           


           


If you copy pf-src entirely, with all members, it is not necessary to first create it in the target library. It will be created automatically with the required record length
CPYF FROMFILE(LIBFROM/SRCFROM) TOFILE(LIBTO/SRCTO) FROMMBR(*ALL) TOMBR(*FROMMBR) MBROPT(*REPLACE) CRTFILE(*YES)


That's a good idea. You can even use that method if you only want one member by using the FROMMBR parameter. FROMMBR(ABC) for just member ABC or FROMMBR(ABC*) to get all the members starting with ABC.
